# Removing a file from TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoise-hg

I'm having problems removing a file from TortoiseHg.

I make the clone, and there are a few test files which I want out. What is the procedure for removing a file from the repository?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the GUI, you can right click on your local directory and choose repository explorer to see what the branches look like.  Then, you will want to remove the files locally, and then next time you commit and push changes they will be gone.  To do this you would right click on the files you want to remove and choose "remove."  It may prompt you to confirm this "clean."  Then, commit and push changes.  When you finsih this, log into your repository (i.e, bitbucket.org, kiln) and confirm your changes.

If you want to do this through the command line, type:

`hg -?` in Windows to see list of commands.  Or, type:

`hg --help` in Linux for the help list.

Comment: thanks nicorellius, got there eventually. Found it via, right click, tortoisehg, then remove files. picked off the ones I didnt need and then synchronized with a push and i then had a new changeset with the right files i wanted to be there. relief!

Comment: Good to hear.  Choose as correct answer if it solved your problem!  Take care ;--)